# Combining multiple table with certain critera for Teradata

Tags: teradata

I'm trying to combine 3 different tables into one with certain criteria.

1. Table 2 - Calculate the Total Weight of the shipments base on Shipper Number and Ship Date
2. Table 3 - Calaculate the Total Revenue Amount base on Shipper Number and Ship Date
3. Result - Combined the tables into a single table.

Additionally, the SQL should also filter for  "Customer Since" <= 720 and "Ship Date" <= 360

(Note: Customer Number = Shipper Number)

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far and where you are failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what you're looking for, but this could get you started

```
SELECT t2.Shipper_Number, t2.Ship_Date, t2.Total_Weight, t3.Total_Revenue
FROM (
  SELECT Shipper_Number, Ship_Date, SUM(Weight) AS Total_Weight
  FROM Table2
  GROUP BY Shipper_Number, Ship_Date
) t2
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Shipper_Number, Ship_Date, SUM(Revenue) AS Total_Revenue
  FROM Table3
  GROUP BY Shipper_Number, Ship_Date
) t3 ON t2.<PK_column> = t3.<PK_column>
```

A few notes:

- INNER JOIN will only return rows that match in both tables
- You can add your `"Customer Since"` and `"Ship Date"` restrictions as `WHERE` clauses in the sub-queries

**Update**
If you want to get one row per (`Shipper_Number, Ship_Date`) group, then you need to make your `JOIN` condition for those two derived tables using that column combination (`Shipper_Number, Ship_Date`).

And if you want to further filter your rows on `"Customer Since"`, then just `JOIN` to the source table and add the filtering condition.  Something like this:

```
SELECT t2.Shipper_Number, t2.Ship_Date, t2.Total_Weight, t3.Total_Revenue
FROM (
  SELECT Shipper_Number, Ship_Date, SUM(Weight) AS Total_Weight
  FROM Table2
  WHERE Ship_Date <= Ship_Date - INTERVAL '360' DAY -- Assumes you want only order that shipped within the last 360 days
  GROUP BY Shipper_Number, Ship_Date
) t2
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Shipper_Number, Ship_Date, SUM(Revenue) AS Total_Revenue
  FROM Table3
  WHERE Ship_Date <= Ship_Date - INTERVAL '360' DAY -- Assumes you want only order that shipped within the last 360 days
  GROUP BY Shipper_Number, Ship_Date
) t3 ON t2.Shipper_Number = t3.Shipper_Number AND t2.Ship_Date = t3.Ship_Date
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.Shipper_Number = t1.Customer_Number -- Get shipper/customer info
WHERE t1."Customer Since" <= "Customer Since" - INTERVAL '720' DAY -- Assuming you want to get customers that are fewer than 720 days old
```

Again, using an `INNER JOIN`, this assumes that matching rows exist in both tables for (`Shipper_Number` and `Ship_Date`), otherwise it won't return that row.

Also, if feasible, you may want to consider combining your `t2` and `t3` tables into a single table based on a common key (`shipper_number, shipping_number`) or just `shipping_number` if it's a unique value.

Comment: I have indicated the PK_Column as Shipper_Number. 
I have tried to run it with WHERE clauses after the "FROM". 
Unfortunately, it is not the expected result. 

Example: Same Shipper_Number with 2 same Ship_Date and return with 2 different Total_Revenue

Please advice if there is any area that i missing out.

Comment: See my update above.  If you still have issues, please post your exact SQL

Comment: This works !! 
The outcome is what i expected after validating it. 
Thanks for the assistance.  :)